# TFVC api: how to get the file properties ('executable' and 'symlink')

Tags: api, tfs, tfvc, tfs-sdk

I have in the TFVC version control some files that are executable and others that are symlinks.

When you look at the changesets in the UI, we could see that the file has a property:
[image: script with executable property]

When using the TFVC API call`VersionControl.QueryHistory()` with the nuget package `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client`, I could also see that the change corresponding to the addition of the file has a property:

[image: file with property from API]

My problem is that using the TFVC Api, I don't know how to get the properties of this change.

**I want to find a way to know what is the type of  this "property" change type that is included in a changeset. Especially how to know if this "property" is the "executable" property or the "symlink" one.**

TFVC seems to know that a file is a symlink because it display a little different icon (notice the arrow):

[image: icon of symlink]

Type of object retrieved:

- changeset: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset`
- change: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Change`
- file/item: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Item` (containing collections named `Attributes`, `Properties` or `PropertyValues` that perhaps could contains the data but that are empty)

Internet or MSDN documentation is of no help here :(

Note: The goal is to add the support to [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [TfvcItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvcitem?view=azure-devops-dotnet) Class in Libray [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client/). TfvcItem object has `IsSymbolicLink` property to determine if the item is symlink or not.

You can get the ChangeSets using [TfvcHttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvchttpclient?view=azure-devops-dotnet) object method, and then
get TfvcItem object. See below example:

```
 string tfsurl= "http://instance/tfs/DefaultCollection";
 string Project = "project";
 
 NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("username", @"password", "domain");
            
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential winCred = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(netCred);
     
 VssConnection _connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(tfsurl), winCred);

 TfvcHttpClient tfvcClient = _connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>(); 

 var changesets = tfvcClient.GetChangesetsAsync().Result;
      
 foreach (var changeset in changesets)
 {
       var changesetRes =  tfvcClient.GetChangesetChangesAsync(changeset.ChangesetId).Result;
            
       foreach (var change in changesetRes) 
       {
          var item = (TfvcItem)change.Item;
       }
  }
```

See below TfvcItem object :

[image]

Comment: For a symlink, the `ItemType` is still `File`. Thanks. I will have a look to `TfvcItem`. Do you have an idea on how to retrieve the 'executable' flag?

Comment: It seems that the boolean `IsSymbolicLink` is always `false`. So this solution is not working :( But I will try some other calls to see if I can have it filled...

Comment: Ok. I'm able to get the `IsSymbolicLink` property filled when calling `GetItemsAsync()`. So it is Ok for that. But for the "executable" flag, do you have an idea?

Comment: How about looking at the item's `extension` in `ContentMetadata`  property of `TfvcItem` object.

Comment: `ContentMetadata` which seems interesting so that I already looked at it but is always `null` :(

Answer (score 0):

"Team Explorer Everywhere" somehow creates a KVP with a key named `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Executable` in what I'm guessing is the `ContentMetadata` which is apparently NULL - where should this data be fetched in the API?

Comment: I didn't have enough of a reputation to add to the previous set of comments.